# When combining several input files into one main file, corresponding .bib files (for each chapter) in biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I have question on which i spent already significant amount of time. Wondering if you could help me, or refer in the direction where I should go.

So the basic goal: is to combine 2 chapters and combine 2 corresponding .bib files (after each chapter) (for the case of simplicity).

I am able to run Latex once, then I run Bibtex. (produce only warnings), then I run LATEX again, and it produces error:

> Undefined control sequence
>   \printbibliography{heading=subbibliography}?

Here is my code:

```
`\documentclass[openany]{report}
%\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage[style=chicago-notes,backend=bibtex,refsegment=chapter,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}

\addbibresource[label=chapter1]{/Volumes/ARKADY/LATEX/chapter1/paper/chapter1.bib}
\addbibresource[label=chapter2]{/Volumes/ARKADY/LATEX/chapter2/tex/chapter2.bib}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Blah bLAH blah}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, 
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[segment=1,heading=subbibliography]

\chapter{blah 2}



quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,
\nocite{*}

\printbibliography[segment=2,heading=subbibliography]

\end{document}`
```

`chapter1.bib`:

```
@techreport{Hoshi,
    Author = {Takeo Hoshi and Takatoshi Ito},
    Date-Added = {2014-12-05 20:17:36 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-12-05 20:18:39 +0000},
    Institution = {NBER},
    Number = {18287},
    Title = {How long will Japanese government bond prices remain high?},
    Type = {Working Paper},
    Url = {http://www.nber.org/papers/w18287.pdf},
    Year = {2012},
}
@techreport{Jeanneret,
    Author = {Alexandre Jeanneret},
    Date-Added = {2014-12-05 20:19:04 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-12-05 20:20:01 +0000},
    Institution = {HEC Montreal},
    Title = {The Dynamics of Sovereign Credit Risk},
    Type = {Working Paper},
    Year = {2012},
}
@techreport{Kopf,
    Author = {Christian Kopf},
    Date-Added = {2014-12-05 20:20:18 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-12-05 20:21:34 +0000},
    Institution = {CEPS},
    Number = {237},
    Title = {Restoring financial stability in the euro area.},
    Type = {Policy Brief},
    Year = {2011},
}
@article{Lane,
    Author = {Philip R. Lane},
    Date-Added = {2014-12-05 20:21:57 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-12-05 20:22:34 +0000},
    Journal = {Journal of Economic Perspectives},
    Number = {3},
    Pages = {49--68},
    Title = {The European sovereign debt crisis},
    Volume = {26},
    Year = {2012}}

@article{Longstaff,
    Author = {Francis A. Longstaff and Jun Pan and Lasse H. Pedersen and Kenneth J. Singleton},
    Date-Added = {2014-12-05 20:23:47 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-12-05 20:24:56 +0000},
    Journal = {American Economic Journal: Macroeconomics},
    Number = {2},
    Pages = {75-103},
    Title = {How Sovereign Is Sovereign Credit Risk?},
    Volume = {3},
    Year = {2011}}

@techreport{Mayer,
    Author = {Manuel Mayer},
    Date-Added = {2014-12-05 20:25:26 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-12-05 20:26:10 +0000},
    Title = {A structural view of sovereign risk contagion in the Euro zone.},
    Type = {Working Paper},
    Url = {http://ssrn.com/abstract=2000662},
    Year = {2013},
}
@article{Mittnik,
    Author = {Stefan Mittnik and Willi Semmler},
    Date-Added = {2014-12-05 20:26:25 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-12-05 20:27:42 +0000},
    Journal = {Journal of Economic Behavior \& Organization},
    Number = {3},
    Pages = {502-522},
    Title = {Regime dependence of the fiscal multiplier},
    Volume = {83},
    Year = {2012}}

@article{Ravn,
    Author = {Morten O. Ravn and Harald Uhlig},
    Date-Added = {2014-12-05 20:28:09 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-12-05 20:29:03 +0000},
    Journal = {Review of Economics and Statistics},
    Number = {2},
    Pages = {371-376},
    Title = {On adjusting the Hodrick-Prescott filter for the frequency of obser- vations.},
    Volume = {84},
    Year = {2002}}
```

`chapter2.bib`

```
@article{Acharya,
    Author = {Viral V. Acharya and Lars A. Lochstoer and Tarun Ramadorai},
    Date-Added = {2014-12-05 21:13:28 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-12-06 02:39:46 +0000},
    Journal = {Journal of Financial Economics},
    Number = {2},
    Pages = {441--465},
    Title = {Limits to arbitrage and hedging: evidence from commodity markets},
    Volume = {109},
    Year = {2013}}

@article{Agnolucci,
    Author = {Paolo Agnolucci},
    Date-Added = {2014-12-05 21:14:54 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-12-05 21:15:41 +0000},
    Journal = {Energy Economics},
    Number = {2},
    Pages = {316--321},
    Title = {Volatility in crude oil futures: A comparison of the predictive ability of GARCH and implied volatility models},
    Volume = {31},
    Year = {2009}}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! A quick hint: If you indent lines of LaTeX code by four spaces -- most easily accomplished by highlighting the lines and clicking on the `{}` "button" in the ribbon above the edit window -- they will be pretty-printed by the site's software.